# Piping heredoc from Perl to Gnuplot

Tags: perl, pipe, gnuplot

Shortly I had problems to get a wall of Gnuplot-commands from a Perl script piped to Gnuplot itself. My main starting reference was on [perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=685819). The subfunction then looked like:

```
sub binPics {

my $inFileName = shift;
my $outFileName = shift;
my $outputFormatPics = shift;

open(GP, "| gnuplot") or die "Error while piping to Gnuplot: $! \n";
    print GP << "   GNU_EOF"

    plot "$inFileName" u 2 lw 2.5 lc 1 , "" u 3 lw 2.5 lc 2
    set terminal $outputFormatPics
    set output '$outFileName.$outputFormatPics'
    replot

    GNU_EOF
}
```

After this a second subfunction is defined with a similar syntax but different Gnuplot commands. I call those subfunctions in the order I defined them. Later in the script the generated pictures are used further. This produces errors.

So what was the problem here and how would a possible running script look like?

I will give my fixed script for this issue but can't explain the heredoc-syntax in its whole. Feel free to do so or to give other suggestions.

/edit

The indentation isn't shown anymore in the SO style. The lines in the heredoc have tabs as the first command (to structure the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem was the missing closing of the filehandle `GP`. Without the closing, the first subfunction caused no problems (or to be more specific: the generaetd pictures which should be used later in the script aren't producing errors here) because the call is closed by the second subfunction because of the second `open(GP, "| gnuplot")`- statement. But in the second subfunction the piping isn't closed and therefore possibly cause errors.

When you close the piping, you also need to add a semicolon at the `print`-statement. I don't know why the script without `close(GP)` has no problems with the missing semicolon and I also don't know if the tab indentation is an issue.

Nonetheless, this works for me and maybe somebody is also interested:

```
sub binPics {

my $inFileName = shift;
my $outFileName = shift;
my $outputFormatPics = shift;

open(GP, "| gnuplot") or die "Error while piping to Gnuplot: $! \n";
print GP << "GNU_EOF";

plot "$inFileName" u 2 lw 2.5 lc 1 , "" u 3 lw 2.5 lc 2
set terminal $outputFormatPics
set output '$outFileName.$outputFormatPics'
replot

GNU_EOF
close(GP);
}
```

Comment: Also remember that bareword filehandles are actually a form of global variable.  If you had defined a lexical filehandle like: `open(my $gp, "| gnuplot")`, it would be automatically closed when it went out of scope at the end of the block.

Comment: Ah this makes sense now, thx! Btw. it seems that the missing `close` is not always a problem for the script.